# copy constructor for a baseclasspointer to a subclass

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have a class(let's call it A) and I want to copy A. So I call A's copy constructor. A has a member of type B* which is a pointer of type B to one of his subclasses.(let's call them B with a number. (ie: B1, B5, ..))
Since I don't want to just copy the address, I call memberofA->copyconstructor from one of the subclasses. The copy constructor in the base class is called from within the copy constructor of the subclass. But is this possible or do i need to dynamic cast the pointer of type baseclass to the correct subclass the pointer is pointing too?

```
 class A {
 public: 
    A(const A& object) {
        // what should i call here to deep copy member
        }
 private:
    B* member //pointer to subclass of B
  };

 class B {
     privatedatamamber
  public:
     B (const B& object) {
        privatedatamember = object->getprivatedatamember(); 
     }
  };

  class B1 : public B {
    privatedatamember
  public:
    B1 (const B1& object) : B(object) {
      privatedatamember = object->getprivatedatamember(); 
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a public function to B:

```
virtual B* Clone() = NULL;
```

B's subclasses must implement this (pure virtual function). 
Here's an example:

B header:

```
virtual B* Clone() = 0; //public
```

B1 header:

```
virtual B* Clone();
```

B1 cpp:

```
B* B1::Clone()
{
   return new B1(*this);
}
```

A:

```
A::A(const A& object) : member(object.member->Clone()) {
}
```

Comment: B1(*this) calls B1's copyconstructor?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: A::A(const A& object) : member((A.getmember)->clone()){}

Comment: @user2321611 - for the first comment the answer is yes, this is the essence if virtual functions. For the second one, I had a bug. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The approach I'd use is to give `B` an abstract method `clone()` returning a `std::unique_ptr<B>` which is implemented in every concrete class to return a copy, e.g.:

```
std::unique_ptr<B> D::clone() const {
    return std::unique_ptr<B>(new D(*this));
}
```

When a deep copy is needed you can then just call `clone()`.

Comment: What is D refering too?

Comment: @user2321611: `D` is just a placeholder for any concrete class derived from `B`, e.g., for you example implement this override for `B1` and any other concrete class deriving from `B`.

Comment: So my copyconstructor in A calls A'smember->clone(); And clone is defined in B1?

Comment: @user2321611: yes. `clone()` is declared an abstract method in `B` and defined in all concrete classes derived from `B`, e.g., in `B1`. I think I already said so.